# add even-listener to a button on timeline that is a grand child of a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I got a simple flash scene that contain movie clip that contain sliding button that changing every few seconds:
[image]

every layer contain a button and another movie clip.
[image]

If I want to add event-listener to a simple button on stage, i just write:

```
f4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f4Click);

function f4Click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("dlHTCMD", "switchtogame?code=fnf50");
}
```

but when I'm trying to access the button inside the two movie clips, like

```
optContainer.optBeach.btnBeach.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnBeachClick);
```

and I'm adding a `trace` function to see if the event are triggered but nothing is happening.

looks like a simple problem but i didn't find a solution.

I thought about extending the button class and add a bind function with the value as the name of the button and set the Event Listener but I'm not an AS3 expert :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Pass mouse events to children
optContainer.mouseChildren = true;
optContainer.optBeach.mouseChildren = true;

// Reset hit area
optContainer.hitArea = null;
optContainer.optBeach.hitArea = null;

// Reset masks
optContainer.mask= null;
optContainer.optBeach.mask= null;
```

Also check whether on each key frame button have name.

Comment: How many frames have optContainer, and optContainer.optBeach? Where you put code `optContainer.optBeach.btnBeach.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnBeachClick);` which frame?